# Removing square brackets in JOLT

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have the jolt **input** below :

```json
{
  "pnum": "4545",
  "clascode": null,
  "retun": "NN",
  "skcmm": [
    "AA",
    "EE",
    "KN",
    "NH",
    "NL"
  ]
}
```

My **current spec**:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "SMS_SPMFORMAT": "${spm_format}",
      "SMS_PRODUCTIONFORMAT": "${partNumberConverted}"
    }
  }
]
```

The current **output**:

```json
{
  "pnum" : "4545",
  "clascode" : null,
  "retun" : "NN",
  "skcmm" : [ "AA", "EE", "KN", "NH", "NL" ],
  "SMS_SPMFORMAT" : "${spm_format}",
  "SMS_PRODUCTIONFORMAT" : "${partNumberConverted}"
}
```

But the **expected output** is :

```json
{
  "pnum" : "4545",
  "clascode" : null,
  "retun" : "NN",
  "skcmm" : "AA,EE,KN,NH,NL",
  "SMS_SPMFORMAT" : "${spm_format}",
  "SMS_PRODUCTIONFORMAT" : "${partNumberConverted}"
}
```

I need to remove the **square brackets** for the lists and add it as string with double quotes.
Can you please help here.

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan : Thank you so much. Had done the changes and working fine. To be frank you are a Jolt expert. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a **join** function for ***skcmm*** after converting the **modify** transformation from ***default*** to ***overwrite*** in order to overwrite the existing value of ***skcmm*** such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "SMS_SPMFORMAT": "${spm_format}",
      "SMS_PRODUCTIONFORMAT": "${partNumberConverted}",
      "skcmm": "=join(',',@(1,&))" // concatenates the components of the array comma-separatedly
    }
  }
]
```

Btw, using the existing **shift** transformation,  which replicates exactly the whole content, is redundant.

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]